# Is there a way to give an id to a datapoint in WPF charts?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF line series chart,
when a datapoint is selected the selection changed event is fired.

What i want to know is, is there a way to give the datapoints ID values so that i can get them from inside the selection event

something like:

```
private void LineSeries_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   int id = ((something)sender).id;
}
```

Comment: replacing **something**  with **FrameworkElement** can help you ?

Comment: @meorfi could elaborate some more please?...still new to WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SelectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx) should provide you the information you need. The property `AddedItems` contains the DataPoints that is/are selected and the property `RemovedItems` contains the DataPoints that where previously selected.

You need to cast the items in the collection to the Type (`DataPoint` or `LineDataPoint` for LineSeries)you need.

```
private void LineSeries_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   DataPoint selectedPoint = null;

   if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0){
     selectedPoint = e.AddedItems[0];
   }
}
```